# Conditions on those Pell-type equations to admit solutions

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

I am facing those generalised Pell equations,

$a^2-Db^2=-8$

and

$x^2-Dy^2=8$,

where $D=t^2+8t$ for an **odd** $t$, $t>2$. In particular, I would like to find the cases where both equations admit (integer) solutions.

I don't know too much about continued fractions and theory of Pell equations, so I tried to work my way isolating $t$. We have (t is positive):

$t=\frac{-4y+\sqrt{16y^2+x^2-8}}{y^2}$,

and so

$t=-4+\frac{\sqrt{16y^2+x^2-8}}{y}$.

In the same way we can find

$t=-4+\frac{\sqrt{16b^2+a^2+8}}{b}$.

But I don't know if this can help me finding a solution. I found some way to compute solutions of a generalised Pell equation given one solution, but I don't think it's useful to me: I don't look for actual solutions for $x$, $y$, $a$, $b$, but for conditions on $t$. I used some online calculator of Pell equations, namely https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM, to investigate solutions, and I checked that, for **odd** $t\leq 131$, if the second equation admits a solution, the first one doesn't. I tried to study some Pell equation theory, but since my $D$ is a variable I don't know how to compute its continued fraction.

**I know the request for $t$ to be odd may seem artificial, but it comes from previous assumptions. I don't know whether we can derive it from the two equations or not. In fact, I'm not very interested in it.**

Comment: Do you want to find solutions given $t$, or do you want to find all $t$ for which simultaneous solutions exist?

Comment: I would like to find all $t$ for which simultaneous solutions exist